# Are character taunts random?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are the character taunts triggered by a specific series of events, or are they random?
It seems like when I get several critical hits, or many kills within a quick period of time my character will have an audio taunt. But I was wondering what exactly triggers them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taunts trigger from getting the Massive Blow award (6+ kills in the span of one second) and from leveling up. (Two separate audio groups; level up taunts will not play after massive blows and vice versa).

Massacre, Destruction, and Survival do not trigger verbal taunts.

Finally, Followers will taunt both upon spotting *and* defeating a rare, unique, or champion pack. (There, a worthy foe! // Now *THAT* was a fight)

Taunts are class specific, but I do not know whether or not they change based on gender as well.

Comment: Is this answer missing something? I'm getting downvotes, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Nope, answer seems correct. Glorious!

Comment: I always cringe when the Templar says "Could we find more like that?" after I narrowly escape death beating a pack of Molten Vortex Extra Fast champions on hardcore.